# Deferent behavior of inheritance visibility in Objective C between class implementation and xibs

Tags: objective-c

I have a ClassA with a xib associated :

```
@interface ClassA : UIViewController
@end


#import "ClassA.h"
@interface ClassA()
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;
@end

@implementation ClassA
....
@end
```

Know i have a ClassB witch inherits from ClassA. ( UIViewController witch a xib)

```
@interface ClassB : ClassA
@end

@implementation ClassB

// Here i can't not access the private property myButton.
@end
```

My question is :

I know that all private class fields ( Methodes, properties,..) can't be accessed in the inherited classes. I know also if i want to access my properties, i just to declare them in the ClassA.h,but i think that IBOUtlet and IBAction should be private. Why Objective C can't have something like Java keywords (private, protected, public). ?

My other question is, in the ClassB.xib, i have assigned the file's owner to ClassB and here i can see the myButton Outlet ( witch is declared private in the ClassA) and i can assign it to an other Button in the ClassB.xib but i can't doing it programmatically.

Why there is a difference between xibs ( file's owner) and the Class's code implementation ( diference in inheritance visibility) ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you can see the `myButton` property in your ClassB.xib since Xcode just looks for IBOutlets, and then in runtime, when the nib is loaded it just sets that property via KVC using `setValue:forKey:`. You could access to `myButton` from ClassB as well with KVC, but you do not want that, otherwise you would have declared the property as public(in the header file).

Answer (score 0):

It's not Java. 
If it is declared as an IBOutlet or IBAction that gives Interface Builder visibility to it.

Comment: But why differences visibility between Interface Builder and Class implementation ?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Outlets/Outlets.html